# How to close the SimpleDialog in flutter after choosing an option

Tags: android, flutter, simpledialog

I added a `SimpleDialog` with 2 options: lost and found. Whenever I make my selection and get redirected to where I want, [the SimpleDialog doesn't close and stays on my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNVpz.png)

The switch:

```
switch (
  await showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: new SimpleDialog(
      title: new Text("Which category?"),
      children: <Widget>[
        new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text("Found"),
          onPressed: () {
            goToCreate();
          },
        ),
        new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text("Lost"),
          onPressed: () {
            //Whatever
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
  )
)
```

And the cases:

```
{
  case "Found":
    goToCreate();
    break;
  case "Lost":
    //Whatever
    break;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code to support your question.

Comment: @TinusJackson i just did

Answer (score 8):

You can do this from the dialog when you press Accept (or whatever):

```
Navigator.pop(context, true); // You could return any Dart type, like an enum
```

From the caller:

```
bool dialogReturnValue = await showDialog(...);
if (dialogReturnValue == true){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From official docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SimpleDialog-class.html

You need to execute inside options' onPressed method this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, ===arguments===);
```

Full example:

```
SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text('Select assignment'),
        children: <Widget>[
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, Department.treasury); },
            child: const Text('Treasury department'),
          ),
          SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context, Department.state); },
            child: const Text('State department'),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

EDIT:

```
switch (
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new SimpleDialog(
          title: new Text("Which category?"),
          children: <Widget>[
            new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text("Found"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, 'Found'); //Close the SimpleDialog then=>
                goToCreate();
              },
            ),
            new SimpleDialogOption(child: new Text("Lost"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, 'Lost'); //For closing the SimpleDialog
                //After that do whatever you want
              },
            ),
          ],
        )
    )
  )
)
```

EDIT 2 (Demo Application):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
          _askedToLead(context);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _askedToLead(BuildContext context) async {
    switch (await showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: const Text('Select assignment'),
            children: <Widget>[
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Found');
                },
                child: const Text('FOUND'),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'Lost');
                },
                child: const Text('LOST'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        })) {
      case 'Found':
        print('FOUND!');
        break;
      case 'Lost':
        print('LOST!');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you check my code above? I just tried to apply this method but it didn't work, maybe you can find the problem?

Comment: I changed the code also created a demo app for your case. I hope it helps.